# gradle how to import external resources

Tags: gradle

I have some static resources that I want to share across multiple projects. I'd like to be able to make a separate gradle build for the static resources, such that I could place the HTML, CSS and JS in somepackage/src/main/resources and then have other gradle builds import somepackage and automatically have the resources imported.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out.  I created another package, with `somepackage/src/main/resources` and an empty `somepackage/build.grade`. In my other project, I simply added the dependency:
`compile(project(':somepackage'))`